# A little problem when I practice in a code website with java

Tags: java

when I use `int a = x`，and finally return `true`，and when I didn't use `int a = x`，then `return false`，tell me why plz

add int a = x
the source code is like that:

```
public class solution009 {
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
    int res = 0;
    int a = x;
    if (x < 0 || x > 0 && x % 10 == 0)
        return false;


    while(x > 0){
        res = res * 10 + x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }

    return res == a;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    solution009 s9 = new solution009();
    System.out.println(s9.isPalindrome(121));
}
```

}

the output is true，when I delete "int a = x",the output is fasle

Comment: post the code please!

Comment: Show code and error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow, This question does not provide enough information always try to provide some information related to what you tried so far with some of your code. Help people to help you. also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Instead of `int a = x`, what did you use? `int a = 0`?

Comment: If you step through the code in your debugger you can see the difference. Note you have to compare with the original value of `x`

Comment: If you delete `int a = x`, you will get an error that variable `a` is not defined

Comment: oh oh,I get it,thank you,I think I am a fool

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet creates a new variable `res` that is constructed from `x` from the right to the left (321 => 123):

```
int res = 0;
while(x > 0){
    res = res * 10 + x % 10;
    x /= 10;
}
```

At the end, `x` is a palindrome if `res == x`.

Your condition `res == a` is working only if `a` equals `x`. And, of course, if you only remove the line `int a`, the code won't even compile...